# Handle Razor Page Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, crash, razor-pages

Hi I'm getting strange behavior in our AspNetCore 2.1 application using Razor Pages. When an exception escapes from a Razor Page action like OnGet the application crashes. The exception never reaches any middleware. It looks like the application *seems* is crashing somewhere in the internal PageActionInvoker.Next method.

I can't paste the code as it far too much. But the following will crash the application:

```
public async void OnGet() {
    await Task.CompletedTask; // normally we await something else
    throw new Exception("Boom!");
}
```

**Note:**

We are:

- combining Views and Razor Pages. The Views are part of the 'older' section of the application.
- we are allowing Razor Page area's.

Do we have to configure some feature?

Are we missing something? Does someone have suggestions?

**FOUND IT**
Nothing special. Well AspNetCore accepts *async void OnGet* and everything works fine UNTIL an exception is raised.

using the following fixed it.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() {
```

Comment: Exceptions in Razor Pages are handled in the same way as MVC, because Razor Pages is a feature of MVC. The error handling code in a Razor Pages template's `Configure` method is identical to what you find in the default MVC project template. Most likely, you are not seeing exceptions because of something unique to your setup.

Comment: Am I missing something? You explicitly have an unhandled exception, so of course the app crashes. Read the docs on handling exceptions, and then do that. If your code is throwing an exception when it shouldn't be, that's a different issue, but then we need to see the actual code to determine why.

Comment: Well I'd assume an exception would bubble up in the middleware so it could be logged and a user could get an internal server error. We're using UseExceptionHandler and UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute both of which aren't reached. I think it's back to finding out what makes our setup 'unique' I was hoping for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even AspNetCore doesn't handle the following construction well:

```
public async void OnGet() {
...
}
```

Even though it's accepted and seems to be working possible exceptions are not handled correctly.

The correct way to do this is:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() {
....
}
```

Don't know whether this classifies as a AspNetCore bug ... in that sense maybe it should be rejected like many other things. Oh well ... bug fixed.

Comment: It's nothing to do with ASP.NET Core. See this: https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Comment: [This post from Stephen Cleary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) on the general topic is also excellent.